# Get JSON data from URL and populate HTML text and disable button based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Newbie here trying to get a landing page for a charity to pull in data using JSON and essentially count down the number of items left in inventory and display that in the HTML, then when the inventory reaches 0 disable the button and change the style on the button. I have been provied a URL with JSON data that looks like this:

```
0:
    Name: "Main Campaign"
    TotalInventory: 18
    AmountRaised: 2200
    remainingInventory: 4
1:
    Name: "Main Campaign - Child 1"
    TotalInventory: 10
    AmountRaised: 1000
    remainingInventory: 0
2:
    Name: "Main Campaign - Child 2"
    TotalInventory: 5
    AmountRaised: 100
    remainingInventory: 3
3:
    Name: "Main Campaign - Child 3"
    TotalInventory: 3
    AmountRaised: 1000
    remainingInventory: 1
```

On the landing page there are 3 different items each with a different inventory amount associated with them. When the inventory number changes in the database it is populated in the JSON URL in real-time and the hope is the landing page will reflect that.

The landing page has 3 different boxes with the same layout that looks like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card mb-5 light-blue">
        <div class="amount"><h4>10 left</h4></div>
             <img class="card-img-top" src="images/donation.jpg" alt="Donation">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4>Donation 1</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Donation description goes here</p>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Donate $50</button>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first snippet block is not JSON.  Can you please show us the actual JSON?

Comment: That is what is displaying at the url, the raw data tab shows this: [{ "Name" : "Main Campaign","TotalInventory" : 18,"AmountRaised" : 2200,"remainingInventory" : 4 },{ "Name" : "Main Campaign - Child 1","TotalInventory" : 10,"AmountRaised" : 1000,"remainingInventory" : 0 },{ "Name" : "Main Campaign - Child 2","TotalInventory" : 5,"AmountRaised" : 100,"remainingInventory" : 3 },{ "Name" : "Main Campaign - Child 3","TotalInventory" : 3,"AmountRaised" : 1000,"remainingInventory" : 1 }]

Answer (score 0):

To fetch your data, use `fetch()`, or `XMLHttpRequest`, depending on which browsers your site needs to support. Once you have the response as a string, just run the `JSON.parse()` function on it, and you'll end up with the array your JSON data represents.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

After that, just perform the DOM manipulations to update your site.